# Find session id with telethon and kill the session

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Before I ask this question I checked [here](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/destroy_session.html). I want to kill all other sessions except the session with which I am connecting now. Based on the telethon api I used `all_sessions = client(GetAuthorizationsRequest()).to_dict()` and I get this result:

```
{
       '_': 'Authorization',
       'api_id': ...,
       'app_name': '...',
       'app_version': '4.1.4',
       'country': 'Unknown',
       'date_active': ...,
       'date_created': ...,
       'device_model': 'SamsungSM-G920F',
       'flags': 0,
       'hash': ...,
       'ip': '...',
       'platform': 'Android',
       'region': '',
       'system_version': 'SDK 23'
}
```

I want to kill this session but I dont know what is te `session id` mentioned in the linke above(telethon API docs). I tried with these to commands:

```
client(DestroySessionRequest(api_id))
client(DestroySessionRequest(hash))
```

But not only no sessions remove but also no response from the apis and the commands waiting and waiting for the response with no error or no exceptions.How can I kill the session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To kill the other sessions, you need to use the `ResetAuthorizationRequest` function.

Example from official documentation:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
from telethon import functions, types
with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    result = client(functions.account.ResetAuthorizationRequest(hash=-12398745604826))
print(result)
```

https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/methods/account/reset_authorization.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
GetSessions = await client(functions.account.GetAuthorizationsRequest()) 
if len(GetSessions.authorizations)>1:
    print("Another Session    :\tYes")
    for ss in GetSessions.authorizations:
        SessionHash = ss.hash
        SessionIp   = ss.ip
        if SessionHash>0:
            result = await client(functions.account.ResetAuthorizationRequest(hash=SessionHash))
            print("Session Killed     :\t" + str(SessionIp)) 
else:
    print("Another Session    :\tNo")
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete current session you:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

# start session
client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash).start()

# Now you can use all client methods listed below, like for example...
client.send_message('me', 'Hello to myself!')


# list all sessions
print(client.session.list_sessions())

# delete current session (current session is associated with `username` variable)
client.log_out()
```

Telethon automatically creates a `.session` file to store the session details every time a new username is used. The file name starts with the username variable (e.g. `my_username.session`). Session files are stored in file system permanently so you can sometimes see several available sessions. You can manually remove session files you do not need and the associated session will not be available anymore.
More info about Telethon sessions could be found in [Telethon API documentation](https://telethon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra/advanced-usage/sessions.html).

Comment: This just deletes the current session file. I want to not only do this with other sessions than the current session but also I want to terminate all other sessions which their session files are not on my local machine

Comment: You can write a script that will manage all your session files and remove ones you do not need.

Comment: If another user has a session file with my account can kill him with telegram app with terminate other sessions section. how can I do it with telethon?